# Bash: tab completion using 'cd' shows both current and home directory contents

Tags: bash, tab-completion

When I attempt tab completion after the ***cd*** command it shows the directories in the current directory *and* also the directories in my home directory.

I've checked the "complete" options, with "complete -p" but there's no "plusdirs" defined (pastebin.com/Z63sCn2s).

What is causing this behaviour?

I'm using: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Comment: Is `CDPATH` set?

Comment: It is. 

$ echo $CDPATH
.:..:/s01/oracle/

This is identical to servers where the unwanted behaviour has not been seen. In fact, this is the only server where I've ever seen this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old topic, but I encountered the same issue. I managed to solve it by explicitly setting `CDPATH=.` and nothing else in my profile file:
https://linux.101hacks.com/cd-command/cdpath/

Answer (score 0):

I try `cd` <kbd>Tab</kbd> show first match dir, to show all option,  continue to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then it shows other option sequentially.